# Continuity and closed images

Tags: continuity, compactness

We have that *f:X->Y is continuous iff for all closed subsets A in Y, the inverse image of A in X is also closed.*

That's sound, and I have no problems to prove it.

However, I am asked to show that f:[0,2π[-> C defined by f(θ)= exp{iθ} don't have an inverse function, although it is continuous and bijective.

Here's my argument:

We have f:[0,2π[ --> Y={z element in C : |z|=1}, defined by f(θ)=exp{iθ}. As this is the exponential function, it is continuous. [0,2π[ is not closed, consequently not compact. As Y is the unit circle, it is compact.

Using argument from a), I can find a closed subset in Y, namely Y itself. But the inverse image of Y is [0,2π[, which is not closed. As I have a closed subset with an inverse image which is not closed, It should follow that f:[0,2π[->Y is not continous, which is clearly wrong!

Could anyone please point out where the mistake in my reasoning is?

Comment: When you say the inverse image of $A$ in $X$ is closed, you are using the relative topology on $X$. So $[0,2\pi[$ is closed in $[0,2\pi[$, no issues

Comment: The previous comment answers your question. For your next one, please note that proper formatting is expected; for information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).